# Connection refused when creating a new LAN socket

Tags: java, sockets

I've been trying to establish a very basic connection between two computers in my LAN. I've viewed several code snippets and went from there, but things seem to fail at the very start: creating a socket.

I've tried it with both connecting to the computer I'm executing the code from (using the hostnames "`Jeroen-DESKTOP`" and "`Localhost`" and the localhost IP "`127.0.0.1`"), and connecting to my laptop (using "`Jeroen-LAPTOP`"). I've tried the ports `6666` and `7598`and opened all TCP connections to it in my firewall settings.

The code I'm using is very basic:

```
socket = new Socket("Jeroen-LAPTOP", 6666);
System.out.println(socket.getPort());
```

With the error being:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at domain.Client.<init>(Client.java:13)
```

Comment: Using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` won't work - those will loop back to the *same* computer. But what's running on Jeroen-LAPTOP? You need something *listening* on that port...

Comment: I've been having some issues with this concept: Am I supposed to run my program in eclipse on my laptop while I attempt to create a socket on my desktop? Is there perhaps a way to do this at just my desktop alone?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, but you'll need to run one program on each computer - one to listen on a port, and the other to connect to that port.

Comment: Oh okay, that clears up a big part of my misconception. Small follow up question: am I to assume from all this that you can't create a socket without an already listening serversocket on the other side?

Comment: Indeed. Where would you expect any data to go?

Comment: You're right, I don't know what I was expecting. Thanks, you've clarified a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what you are doing -

Assuming you are opening a socket on Machine A and trying to connect to it using Machine B, then the typical scenario in Java would be.

Machine A:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(4444);
Socket connection = server.Accept();
```

Machine B:

```
Socket sock = new Socket(MACHINE-A-IP, 4444);
```

This would require exception handling etc to allow it to work. You can see examples here;
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Regarding your comment - yes you can run them both locally.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely have a look at those examples!